# TypeError after upgrading Node version

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs, yarnpkg

I'm trying to fix this problem for 6 hours now and I'm slowly starting to lose my mind, so please excuse my generic question.

First of all I am using:

**Node: 8.10.0 | npm: 5.6.0 | Yarn: 1.5.1**

I just upgraded my project to Node v8 and npm refused to install all dependencies, so i **installed yarn** which fixed the issue immediately.

My sources are compiled using Laravel Mix which utilises Webpack, Babel, ... internally.

Installing and compiling of my sources works perfectly fine now but for some reason **my compiled js file is not working anymore** (even if I downgrade to the previous Node version - 6.10.0).

```
Uncaught TypeError: fn.bind is not a function
at nativeBind (admin.js?id=8c4a6887899977ba8021:72515)
at initMethods (admin.js?id=8c4a6887899977ba8021:75849)
at initState (admin.js?id=8c4a6887899977ba8021:75617)
at Vue._init (admin.js?id=8c4a6887899977ba8021:76936)
at new Vue (admin.js?id=8c4a6887899977ba8021:77037)
at Object../resources/assets/js/admin.js (admin.js?id=8c4a6887899977ba8021:83350)
at __webpack_require__ (admin.js?id=8c4a6887899977ba8021:20)
at Object.1 (admin.js?id=8c4a6887899977ba8021:83790)
at __webpack_require__ (admin.js?id=8c4a6887899977ba8021:20)
at ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":["> 2%"],"uglify":true}}]],"plugins":["transform-object-rest-spread",["transform-runtime",{"polyfill":false,"helpers":false}]]}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/components/Autocomplete.vue.Object.defineProperty.value (admin.js?id=8c4a6887899977ba8021:63)
```

I have aboslutely no ideas what this error means let alone what causes it.

I know that the error message is pretty generic and could probably mean a lot of things but hopefully someone knows what it means given my context.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Ortomala Lokni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49414121/2078468)'s answer pushed me in the right direction.

For some reason I thought my problem was related to my build scripts, npm, webpack or anything of that sort, which - of course - it was not.

Event though it wasn't really an API change as he suggested there was simply a wrong call to the VueJS constructor in my JS file which, for some reason, had been ignored by a previous release of VueJs but apparently not by the current one.

For anyone experiencing some weird bugs that just don't make sense I recommend the following:

- First of all: Determine what really is your problem - if it compiles it is most certainly not related to your JS build
- Comment out all of your JS code in your main file
- The error should be gone at this point
- Narrow down the error by trying to uncomment line by line (or block by block) and test your code after each uncomment

Even though this steps might seem obvious you can easily forget about such simple thing because of the million things that could possibly break when working with modern JS.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime when you upgrade libraries you have to adapt some code. As Javascript is not a typed language, the problem does't appears at compile time but at run time.

In your case, I suppose that you have a problem similar as [this one](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2428).

Check which libraries yarn has upgraded and verify if some API has changed.

Comment: Thanks for your hint - however as yarn is using the same package.json file it can only perform minor version upgrades in my setup. I will check it anyways!